# Removing gloss effect on AppStore icon with IOS 5 xcode 4 app?

Tags: xcode4, ios5, icons

Hi there I just uploaded a new app to the App Store. It all looks great but in the App Store my icon appears with a gloss effect. I changed the relevant "Icon already includes gloss effects = YES" in my XCode and the icon doesn't have gloss on the device when I download it (tried multiple devices).

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Settings for how your app appears in the App Store are in iTunes Connect. You can't change the icon for a version that is approved by Apple, but when you create a new version, check the settings on the icon before submitting.

Comment: Hmmm I can see how you can upload a new icon but there doesn't seem to be an option to remove the gloss effect? Apple is adding the gloss it's not on my icon art work??